# Localstorage in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have an input type text box value is to be stored on local storage upon button submitted

```
<html>
<body action="Servlet.do" >
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<button type="submit"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

How to store in localstorage upon submit button?

Comment: you click a button and submit a form. you need to add an event listener `click` and then do your write logic with localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick function of submit button please execute below code to store textbox value in localstorage with key "a".

```
localStorage.setItem("a", document.getElementsByName('a').value);
```

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body action="Servlet.do" >
    <input type="text" name="a"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="storeVal();">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function storeVal(){
  localStorage.setItem("a", document.getElementsByName('a').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if localstorage is supported by target browser from this list http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage. Then you can use **localStorage.setItem** to set a value and **localStorage.getItem** to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

*Local Storage works as key/value where I use [inputValue] as key*

**jQuery**

```
localStorage.inputvalue = $('input').val()
```

To get the value from LocalSorage you do like this:

```
$('input').val(localStorage.inputvalue)
```